# SNS Application Events get user data from endpoint

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, boto, boto3, amazon-sns

I have an amazon SNS application (GCM). I have configured it to trigger a lambda function to execute when a new platform endpoint is created. I need to add the platform endpoint to my users database. The username associated with the endpoint is sent as "User Data".

I want to use the lambda function to add the endpoint arn to the users DB entry.

When I get the JSON data to lambda, the only useful thing I have is the endpoint ARN of the new token. The user data is not sent. Therefor I need to be able to look it up using boto, but I have not been able to find a way to do this. How would I lookup user data given the endpoints ARN?

JSON data given to lambda funciton:

```html
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "afb28e95-f8cb-5622-a6ad-dccb37f6b07a",
  "TopicArn" : "<Censored>",
  "Subject" : "EndpointCreated event message",
  "Message" : "{\"EndpointArn\":\"<Censored>\",\"EventType\":\"EndpointCreated\",\"Resource\":\<Censored>\",\"Service\":\"SNS\",\"Time\":\"2017-10-16T15:15:09.097Z\",\"Type\":\"EndpointCreated\"}",
  "Timestamp" : "2017-10-16T15:15:09.181Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "<Censored>",
  "SigningCertURL" : "<Censored>",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=<Censored>",
  "Attributes" : {
    "EndpointArn" : "<Censored>",
    "EventType" : "EndpointCreated",
    "Resource" : "<Censored>",
    "Service" : "SNS",
    "Time" : "2017-10-16T15:15:09.097Z",
    "Type" : "EndpointCreated"
  },
  "MessageAttributes" : {
    "AWS.SNS.OldAttributeTransport" : {"Type":"String","Value":"{\"EndpointArn\":\"<Censored>\",\"EventType\":\"EndpointCreated\",\"Resource\":\"<Censored>\",\"Service\":\"SNS\",\"Time\":\"2017-10-16T15:15:09.097Z\",\"Type\":\"EndpointCreated\"}"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boto3 has a SNS method that sounds like what you're looking for: `GetEndpointAttributes`.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns')
response = client.get_endpoint_attributes(EndpointArn="INSERT-ARN")
print(response["Attributes"]["CustomUserData"])
```

HTH

Documentation found [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.get_endpoint_attributes).

Comment: I cant believe I overlooked that. I stared at that page for hours yesterday trying everything. THANK YOU!